# In Kotlin application - read failed, socket might closed or timeout?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an app that is trying to create a ble connection between a phone and another device.   However when it tries to make the connection it gets this error:

`E/THE ERROR: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`

It throws this error at the first exception in the code below:

```
private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket?

 override fun run() {

        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType)
        name = "ConnectThread" + mSocketType

        mAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()



        try {

           mmSocket?.connect()
            mmSocket?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("THE ERROR", e.localizedMessage)

            try {
                mmSocket?.close()
            } catch (e2: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2)
            }

            connectionFailed()
            return
        }


        synchronized(this) {
            mConnectThread = null
        }

        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType)
    }`
```

Absolutely mystified by this.  Grateful for any help.

Edit - the connected method looks liek this:

```
 @Synchronized fun connected(socket: BluetoothSocket?, device: BluetoothDevice?, socketType: String) {
    Log.d("TESTTT", "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType)

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread?.cancel()
        mConnectThread = null
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread?.cancel()
        mConnectedThread = null
    }

    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread?.cancel()
        mSecureAcceptThread = null
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread?.cancel()
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null
    }


    mConnectedThread = ConnectedThread(socket, socketType)
    mConnectedThread?.start()

    val msg = mHandler?.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME, device?.name)
    msg?.data = bundle
    mHandler?.sendMessage(msg)

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you see the first catch? And then what happens with: `connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType)` ?

Comment: yep definitly see it.  It doesn't get to connected but the function is now in the question, thanks!

Comment: How do you create the socket? If you're using BLE, "cancelDiscovery" should only be used for Bluetooth Classic. And if you use GATT then you shouldn't use Bluetooth sockets at all.